# only last curve with marker is plotted in for loop - how to plot all markers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a list of markers in which each marker is used to show the max value of that curve. (4 curves -> 4 markers)

Somehow I cannot get all the markers to appear in the plot. It seems only the first marker in the for loop is plotted.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(18, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
#df0 = pd.read_excel("est.xlsx")
df0.plot()
mylist = list(df0)
# df=df.astype(float)

mrkr = ['o', '.', 'v', 'x']
mrkr_df = pd.DataFrame(mrkr)

idx_mx_vals = []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if df0[mylist[i]][0] > 0:
        idx_mx_vals.append(df0[mylist[i]].idxmax())
    else:
        idx_mx_vals.append(df0[mylist[i]].idxmin())

mx_vals = []
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if df0[mylist[i]][0] > 0:
        mx_vals.append(df0[mylist[i]].max())
    else:
        mx_vals.append(df0[mylist[i]].min())

d = {}
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    d[df0.columns[i]] = [idx_mx_vals[i], mx_vals[i], mrkr[i]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

for col in range(len(mrkr_df.columns)):
    plt.plot(df.iloc[0, col], df.iloc[1, col], marker=mrkr_df.iloc[2, col],
             markersize=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your code, use `idxmax` directly on the absolute values as a vectorial call. You also do not need to create intermediates DataFrames to hold the idxmax/max (I still showed a simpler method to compute it).

Here is a simple version to plot your curves and the greatest extremum. I also added the same color to match the lines.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(18, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
#df0 = pd.read_excel("est.xlsx")
ax = df0.plot()

mrkr = ['o', '.', 'v', 'x']
mrkr_df = pd.DataFrame(mrkr)

idx_mx_vals = df0.abs().idxmax().to_list()

mx_vals = df0.to_numpy()[idx_mx_vals, np.arange(len(idx_mx_vals))].tolist()

# not needed
#df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df, zip(idx_mx_vals, mx_vals, mrkr))))

for x, y, m, line in zip(idx_mx_vals, mx_vals, mrkr, ax.lines):
    ax.plot(x, y, marker=m, c=line.get_color(), markersize=20)
```

output:

[image: plot with markers]

Comment: Thanks alot for this very efficient way! My real data will have 18 curves. Could we add "general" markers for each of the curves to help distinguish the curves even more while retaining the "max" markers?

Comment: you can pick from the many existing [markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html)

Comment: or maybe I misundertood the question?

Comment: with 18 curves, the colour scheme alone makes it difficult to interpret them when reading the legend. I think adding additional markers would help distinguish.

Comment: visually, I think 18 curves is to much in single plot. You can consider stacking (multiple rows) the plot,maybe?

Comment: How would i get the legend to show the 4 markers?

Comment: @user9106985 you would need to craft a custom legend (or also enumerate the names and add `label=name` but you'll have duplicated legends)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
for col in range(len(mrkr_df.columns)):
    plt.plot(df.iloc[0, col], df.iloc[1, col], marker=mrkr_df.iloc[2, col],
             markersize=20)
```

with:

```
for col, m in enumerate(mrkr):
    plt.plot(df.iloc[0, col], df.iloc[1, col], marker=m, markersize=20)
```